# Pulling CSV file from server and displaying on a site

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have methods for converting to data tables and then to HTML on my web page, but I'm not sure after looking around exactly how to get that file from the server. Are there built in ways to grab a file from a server given the name of the server and file path? I'm guessing it's similar to getting data from a database.

Comment: I saw that, it's similar with what I need to do but I'm trying to download it from a server and i don't know how to specify that in place of the "url" from that link.

Comment: Just specify the resource you can access, I have done something similar with a shared folder on a windows server so its formatted as \\hostname\share\file.csv

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I'm assuming I will need to open the connection to the server first or is connecting through visual studio enough?

Comment: Using the `GetCSV` method in the link above will open it for you, so long as you (or wherever the code is running from) can access the csv file on the server and is given a valid path to it you will get back a string containing the entire csv.